# Yahoo Fantasy Sports API Oauth Verifier Not Available

Tags: yahoo

I'm trying to create a program in Python that uses data from Yahoo Fantasy Sports API (Football to be specific). I've already registered an desktop app on the Yahoo Developer Network in order to get permission to use OAuth. I've also gotten the correct urls, client key, and client secret and other necessary information to run the program.

Currently, I am using this website as a resource: https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html

I managed to complete the **get request token phase **, but am now stuck at the **authorization phase**, requiring me to get an **oauth token and oauth verifier i believe**.

However, I'm only able to receive an oauth token, and the methods I call do not return an oauth verifier at all, making it impossible to proceed to the **access token step**. I'm just looking for some possibilities as to why this is the case.

Thanks.

```
import csv
import requests
import sys
import time
import webbrowser
from oauth_hook import OAuthHook
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs



access_token_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token"
request_token_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token"
base_authorization_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth"
callback_URL = "auto-manager.com"

client_key =  ".."  #can't reveal actual client stuff here

client_secret = ".."

#get request token
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key,client_secret=client_secret)
print oauth
fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

print fetch_response

print resource_owner_key
print resource_owner_secret

# get authorization, returns no verifier but returns a token for some reason, PROBLEM's here
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print 'please go here and authorize,', authorization_url
redirect_response = raw_input('Paste full redirect URL here: ')
oauth_response = oauth.parse_authorization_response(redirect_response)
print oauth_response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue i've found with **requets_oauthlib** is that it doesn't let you kind of *customize* stuff such as *headers* and *body* content. I've tried to use it for *Yahoo OAuth* but i got stuck because of that.
I turned to **rauth**, with which i managed to make things work. I even developed a special **OAuth Lib for Yahoo** which supports **OAuth1 and OAuth2**.
The lib is named [yahoo-oauth](https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-oauth).

Hope it will help you out.

Have a good one

Comment: I saw this block in your repo:

# Example
response = oauth.session.post(url, data=body)

What should the url parameter be and what does data = body do?

Comment: Hi, this is just a an example of how to use the session. **yahoo-oauth** uses **rauth** which uses **[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)**. So once you have you have you **access_token**, do run ***get, post, put, ... *** request. Here is an [example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) from the requests documentation